# Buscador de base de datos con ajax y js no responde

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, buscador

realize un buscador con ajax para mi base de datos en MySql, el buscador busca 3 datos, Id, Nombre y una imagen, cuando lo uso en mi aplicacion web me funciona a la perfeccion, pero despues de hacer unas 3 busquedas se empieza a tardar como 1 minuto, y como en la 4 o 5 ya no busca nada. Ya cheque mi conexion y es correcta, y tambien es necesario decirles que las primeras busquedas tardan alrededor de 5 o 6 segundos. Si tienen alguna otra duda o quieren saber otro fragmento de mi codigo diangme. Gracias

Este es mi codigo de  js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search').focus()

  $('#button').on('click', function(){
    var search = $('#search').val()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'mostrar.php',
      data: {'search': search},
      beforeSend: function(){
        $('#result').html('<img src="img/pacman.gif">')
      }
    })
    .done(function(resultado){
      $('#result').html(resultado)
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('Hubo un error :(')
    })
  })
})
```

Mi codigo php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tabla.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif|Poppins|Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
<head>
    <title>Mostrar imagenes</title>
</head>
<body>
   <center>
       <table id="mitabla" border="1">
       <thead>
       <tr>
          <th colspan="6"><a href="index2.php" class="Titulo">Volver</a></th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <th>id</th>
           <th>Nombre</th>
           <th>Imagen</th>
           <th colspan="2">Opciones</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php
        include("conexion.php");
          $mysqli = getConnexion();
       $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
  $query = "SELECT id, nombre, Imagen FROM tabla_imagen WHERE nombre LIKE '%$search%' ";
         $res = $mysqli->query($query);

    while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
            <td><img height="80px" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['Imagen']); ?>"/></td>
            <th><a href="modificar.php?Id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Modificar</a></th>
            <th><a href="eliminar.php?Id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Eliminar</a></th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        }

        ?>   
    </tbody>
</table>
   </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me di cuenta sobre el $mysqli = getConnexion(), no es correcto? sería getConexion(); en php, por alguna razón. No te olvides de revisar correctamente la página de "conexion.php". Espero que te haya ayudado, saludos

Comment: Jajajajaj, perdon es una costumbre mia escribirlo asi, gracias por la sugerencia de todas maneras ;)